# Can't fetch number of cells in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a main tableViewController, touch a button self.navigation will push addItem viewController, click save self.navigation with pop the add VC, then we're back on the main one, I successfully add and save, also fetch, but when it comes to fetching number of cells, number returns 0, heres the method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]     objectAtIndex:section];
NSLog(@"No. of cells determined: %lu", (unsigned long)[secInfo numberOfObjects]);
return[secInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

NSLog gives me 0, whats the problem, this gave me headache.

Here's the fetch request:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController {

// Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Goal"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title"
                                                               ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];




// setting _fethcedResultsController
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:nil];




// setting _fetchedResultsController to self
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; // for the tableview updating thing



// Thats it
return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Please note that when I run a check for items, it's not nil:

```
// fetching all items to check how many of them exists
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Goal"
                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;

NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *goals = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];

NSLog(@"No. of goals: %lu", (unsigned long)[goals count]);
// end of check for items
```

Comment: Do you use Core Data? Show please your `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: use breakpoint or print what contain in NSError *fetchError. There might some error in fetchrequest

Comment: Have you implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods: controllerWillChangeContent, didChangeSection, didChangeObject, controllerDidChangeContent ?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to put this code of line:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
 }
```

in method

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController;
```

so before I did, the app always creates new fetchedResultsController and over-write the old one.